# Running Totals in a Persisted Computed Column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerLedgerEntries]
(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustReference] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DebitAmount] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,    
    [CreationTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [ProductId] [nvarchar](32) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.CustomerLedgerEntries] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to add a calculated, persisted column that will give me the running balance of each customer. Presently I use this query to obtain the running balance of each customer:

```
SELECT 
    Id, CustReference, CreationTime, DebitAmount, CreditAmount, 
    SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustReference ORDER BY Id 
                                          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Balance 
FROM
    CustomerLedgerEntries
```

I tried to add the computed column using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerLedgerEntries 
    ADD Balance AS (SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustReference 
                                                          ORDER BY Id 
                                                          ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING));
```

But it throws an error:

> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

How can I achieve this please?

**Edit 1:**
After following @JM_ suggestion below and creating a UDF, in the table the balance shows as below:

`Id CusReference CreationTime DebitAmount CreditAmount Balance
30  3      2017-07-12 15:26:36.753  15000.00    0.00    14000.00
31  3      2017-07-12 15:26:36.753  0.00    1000.00     14000.00`

Whereas when I run the query `Select    Id, CustReference, CreationTime, DebitAmount, CreditAmount
        , Sum(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) Over( Partition By CustReference Order by Id 
                                    rows Unbounded Preceding) As Balance 
 From   CustomerLedgerEntries` the result shows correctly:

`30 3   2017-07-12 15:26:36.753   15000.00  0.00      15000.00
31  3   2017-07-12 15:26:36.753   0.00      1000.00   14000.00`

So almost there... but not quite there. Please is there any help?

Comment: what you are trying to do is not supported,as computed column has info only about the row that is inserted..you can create a view though

Comment: It's not supported because it's not deterministic.  Since a new record could be added with an earlier ID causing all records after that ID, for a given custReference, to be re-evaluated; the engine is unable to update more than this one record.  What you're seeking to do is not possible in a computed column.

Comment: What about with a UDF in the computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your table has a Credit Column, but the script above did not include it.  You can do it by using a UDF:

--EDIT:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_GetBalance] (@CustRef bigint, @ID bigint)
RETURNS decimal(18,2)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Balance decimal(18,2)
  SELECT @Balance = SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY CustReference ORDER BY Id 
                                      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM
CustomerLedgerEntries WHERE CustReference =@CustRef and ID <= @id


RETURN @Balance
END


ALTER TABLE CustomerLedgerEntries ADD Balance as (dbo.UDF_GetBalance(CustReference, ID))
```

Comment: please see my **Edit 1** above, if there is any way you can help?

Comment: Changed it to use the ID to keep it to only the current record and below

Comment: Awesome! Works @JM_. Thank you a million!

Answer (score 1):

Using a scalar udf in a computed column for this is an awful Idea for a numbers of reasons. One huge problem is that queries against that table, even when the computed column is not referenced, will run serially. Here's a great article that explains why you don't want to do this:[Another reason why scalar functions in computed columns is a bad idea](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/another-reason-why-scalar-functions-in-computed-columns-is-a-bad-idea/)

SQL Server 2012 offers the ability to do index [builds/rebuilds in parallel](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189329(v=sql.110).aspx) but you lose that functionality when you use a scalar udf in this way. You can test this for yourself by using the traceflag referenced in [this article](https://www.google.com/search?q=paul%20white%20parallelism%20traceflag&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS750US750&oq=paul%20white%20&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j69i65j0j69i59j69i61j69i59.4559j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Scalar functions are bad for many other reasons too. For optimal performance that does restrict serial execution on your CustomerLedgerEntries table I would use an iTVF (note that I can't test this). An iTVF will allow you use ***all*** your CPUs.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UDF_GetBalance (@CustRef bigint)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
  SELECT balance = SUM(DebitAmount - CreditAmount) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY CustReference ORDER BY Id ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM CustomerLedgerEntries 
WHERE CustReference =@CustRef;
GO
```

Comment: I created this iTVF, but I don't know how to use it. How do I?